# MixRGB vs Math for greyscale

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm currently using Blender 2.8, but this applies to 2.79 too.

In the shader graph when using scalar/greyscale values is there any difference between using the Math node and MixRGB for the operators that exist in both?

e.g. if I use multiply in MixRGB is it going to give me inferior results to using multiply in a Math node? Particularly when generating textures from different noises and mixing them to create maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question to one of the developers of Blender at the Blender Conference in 2019 and he said that they are identical.