# MixRGB vs math performance for single/greyscale values

Tags: shaders, color, color-management, development, shader-nodes

I would like to know if MixRGB still calculates the three color channels if the input is a number or grayscale value. I am aware the result is the same either way but, this matters for simplifying and speeding up calculations.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147112/mixrgb-vs-math-for-greyscale) asks a similar question, but it doesn't cite any sources or specify if there's a change in performance, as if the answer just said the result is the same.

vs math performance for single/greyscale values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you with 100% certainty without doing testing that you could do as well yourself-- really, testing that *only* you can do, because the details are going to depend on your specific machine.

Blender compiles shader nodes to shader code that runs directly on your video card.  One optimization of these cards is that they're designed to do "SIMD", which stands for Same Instruction, Multiple Data.  In particular, they're explicitly designed to operate on four different sets of data at the same time (which could be a 2x2 group of pixels, an RGBA color, an xyzw position/normal/whatever, or a 4x4 matrix.)  If Blender's designed well, and your video card is designed well, doing a 3-channel MixRGB should be no slower than doing a 1-channel MixRGB.  Your video card may in fact be running any operations that operate on single channels four-fold, just because it's designed to do so.

If, somehow, one of those things is *not* designed well, well, you'd have to have things pretty darned tuned before MixRGB ended up being the bottleneck for whatever you're doing.  MixRGB is about as fast of a shader operation as you can get.

In general, optimizing around things at this low of a level is *very* dependent on your specific hardware and machine, and somebody running Nvidia may very well reach a different conclusion than somebody running AMD.  For the people that care about this deeply-- ie, game devs-- they do not follow particular rules in regards to this, but instead look at actual performance on a variety of testbeds.